# Drag and Flick Objects to any position (Unity3D)

Tags: unity, android

In unity, I have several boxes in one cluster. I want the user to be able to move any of these boxes to any position that they desire in the app, and have it stay there until they move it again. Also, I want the user to be able to flick any boxes and when it is flicked, have it bounce around the screen, as if it were trapped inside of the phone (but never leaving it). Any way I can do this? (This will be used for an Android Experiment)

Comment: Are you wanting this to be done in 2D or 3D?

Comment: Using Unity 3D..